# How do I center a basket attachment that's sitting between the stem and head tube

Tags: stem, basket, headtube

I messed up while building my daughter's bike and started turning this basket attachment around, until I realized I am looking at it from the wrong side. Now it's sitting at an angle.

[image]

What tool should I use to loosen this element up and rotate it back to where it was? I am using wrench on it but it seems to require extreme force, I must be doing something wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That bracket is wedged between the components that make up your upper headset bearing.

The minimum you need is a big spanner that will fit the top nut (the locknut) and you want to avoid adjusting the knurled ring below the bracket.  If it moves then your steering could get sloppier.

It is not a big job at all, but be mindful of the bearing.

Comment: Ok, so put a big spanner on the top nut and then what, move it in the direction I want the bracket to go? Does this tighten/untighten anything?

Comment: @hyankov If the knurled nut doesn't move, then it will be unchanged in the bearing preload.  If the knurled nut moves, then yes the headset bearing tension will change.  The black bracket is just held by friction under the hexagonal nut.  Try backing that nut off a quarter turn and tapping the bracket into alignment.